# Apache-Beam + Python: Writing JSON (or dictionaries) strings to output file

Tags: python, json, dictionary, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to use a Beam pipeline in order to apply the SequenceMatcher function to a ton of words. I (hopefully) have figured everything out except the WriteToText part.

I have defined a custom ParDo (hereby called ProcessDataDoFn) that takes the main_input and the side_input, process them and output dictionaries like this one

```
{u'key': (u'string', float)}
```

My pipeline is quite simple

```
class ProcessDataDoFn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element, side_input):

    ... Series of operations ...

    return output_dictionary

with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:

    # Main input
    main_input = p | 'ReadMainInput' >> beam.io.Read(
        beam.io.BigQuerySource(
            query=CUSTOM_SQL,
            use_standard_sql=True
        ))

    # Side input
    side_input = p | 'ReadSideInput' >> beam.io.Read(
        beam.io.BigQuerySource(
            project=PROJECT_ID,
            dataset=DATASET,
            table=TABLE
        ))

    output = (
        main_input
        | 'ProcessData' >> beam.ParDo(
            ProcessDataDoFn(),
            side_input=beam.pvalue.AsList(side_input))
        | 'WriteOutput' >> beam.io.WriteToText(GCS_BUCKET)
    )
```

Now the problem is that if I leave the pipeline like this it only output the key of the output_dictionary. If I change the return of ProcessDataDoFn to json.dumps(ouput_dictionary), The Json is written correctly but like this

```
{
'
k
e
y
'

:

[
'
s
t
r
i
n
g
'

,

f
l
o
a
t
]
```

How can I correctly output the results?

Comment: In your code the class  is declared as `ProcessData` then when you use it in the pipeline it is `ProcessDataDoFn`. I'm sure that's just a typo in the question but would be helpful to correct it.

Comment: Thanks, it should be fixed by now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually partially solved the issue.

The ParDoFn that I wrote either return a dictionary or a JSON formatted string. In both cases, the problem arises when Beam tries to do something with said input. Beam seems to iterate over a given PCollection if said PCollection is a dictionary, it only gets its key, if said PCollection is a string, it iterates over all the character (that's why the JSON output is so strange). I find the solution to be rather simple: encapsulate either the dictionary or the string in a list. The JSON formatting part can either be done at the ParDoFn level or via a Transform like the one you showed.

Comment: As stated in the Python API [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/pydoc/2.0.0/apache_beam.transforms.html#apache_beam.transforms.core.ParDo):
"Note that the DoFn must return an iterable for each element of the
input PCollection. An easy way to do this is to use the yield keyword in the process method."

Comment: I'd love to see your `ProcessDataDoFn()` if you could. Did you just end up using `yield` for each dict in the list?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is proprietary code, but yes, the yield solved it for me.

Comment: It's a strange quirk of python that a string is iterable, but then slicing iand list functions become possible. I guess the PCollection is just expecting an iterable, and there's probably a use case for turning a string into a PCollection for processing character by character.

Answer (score 7):

It's unusual that your output looks like that. `json.dumps` should print json in a single line, and it should go out to files line-by-line.

Perhaps to have cleaner code, you can add an extra map operation that does your formatting however way you need. Something like so:

```
output = (
  main_input
  | 'ProcessData' >> beam.ParDo(
        ProcessDataDoFn(),
        side_input=beam.pvalue.AsList(side_input))
  | 'FormatOutput' >> beam.Map(json.dumps)
  | 'WriteOutput' >> beam.io.WriteToText(GCS_BUCKET)
)
```

Comment: Is there a reason to recommend mapping `json.dumps` function to the elements in the `pcoll` rather than using `ParDo` to apply a `DoFn`? It seems like DoFn has metrics and other benefits or do you think it is too much overhead for a simple transform case like this?

Comment: A `Map` gets translated into a `ParDo`, so whatever fits your use case works. If you want the extra features, go for `ParDo`. : )